# adding 2 decimal points to double

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I been playing with this and can't seem to get the format correct.
I have a float **14.237260**

I need to format it to:
**14.237.260**

so I tried :

```
freq.ToString("#.000.000");
```

and no good also tried

```
String.Format("{0:#.000.000}",freq).
```

I can't seem to get the last part of the format  **.260** i'm always getting **14.237260**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot is a [special character in the format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) - it signifies the decimal place. There can only be one *actual* decimal place, so the second dot is ignored.

You can quote a string to have it echoed verbatim in the output, so try this:

```
freq.ToString("#.000'.'000");
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8vverZ) showing your expected output.

Comment: outstanding, worked and I did not know about the second decimal place thanks again!